# Xamarin Forms TapGestureRecognizer not working iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have been facing an issue many have been in the past but none of the solutions seem to work.

I have a Grid with in it a StackLayout with TapGesture.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WodTracker.App.Components"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WodTracker.App.Pages.Account.PinCodePage"
             BackgroundColor="White">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="NumberCommand" CommandParameter="1"/>
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"  Text="1"  FontSize="Title" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"></Label>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text=" " FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The code that should be hit is as followed. No initializing in the constructor just method.

```
private async void NumberCommand(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     var button = sender;
}
```

On Android the Tapped Command "NumberCommand" is executed. But on iOS it does not fire.
On this [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134742/xamarin-forms-tapgesturerecognizer-not-working-on-ios) I have found people mentioning

```
InputTransparent="True"
```

I have tried adding this to the Parent Grid and the StackLayout without any success.

Hope someone can help.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2244

**Solved**

It was an issue with 'InputTransparent="True"', after rebuilding the page step by step based on comments from ToolmakerSteve I was able to fix it. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: First, FYI: `InputTransparent="True"` causes an element to be IGNORED by input. You definitely DO NOT want that on the element. (The cases where people use it, are when another element is "in front of" the one that should receive input. They put it on that "front" element, so that input can "go through it" to what is behind.) google `xamarin forms inputtransparent`.

Comment: Add to your question **the complete xaml of the page**. You can **leave out most details** if you want, but need to see the beginning and end of **ALL** elements on the page. Something like `<ContentPage> <Grid> <StackLayout></StackLayout> <someotherelement></someotherelement> </Grid> </ContentPage>`, but with each element on its own line. Perhaps one of the OTHER elements needs `InputTransparent`. Though then I would expect it to fail on Android also.

Comment: Also show **All Gesture Recognizers** in that XAML, if there are others on the page.

Comment: I test your code everything works on iOS . Pls provide all the elements in xaml . BTW are you using hot restart or not ?

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve, I just added the full code if have been trying, only one StackLayout with gestures.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT, I updated the code, I tried both while using Hot Reload and without.

Comment: That XAML looks good. Add to question all code for `NumberCommand`. Need to see 1) the declaration, `public Command NumberCommand { get; set; }` or similar. 2) the line of code that sets it, probably in constructor. 3) The declaration of the method that gets called, when the command is activated. OR that might be part of (2).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks, I added the code. It is just a method.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I was thinking about “{Binding NumberCommand}”. Binding would use the details I asked for, but this isn’t binding. I don’t see anything wrong. I’ll test in a little while.

Comment: I've tested this code, and it works fine on iOS for me. You can see this in [my TestXFBugs repo](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/TestXFBugs). I use this for different tests, so in App.xaml.cs, make sure "MainPage = new PinCodePage();" is not commented out. Tested on iOS Simulator, iOS 15.0. Tested in VS 2019 from PC, and in VS on Mac.

Comment: Manage Nugets for Solution / Updates / Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2291. On the mac, in your project, find /bin and /obj folders, delete them - to be 100% sure everything gets rebuilt. Consider testing directly on Mac, using updated VS on Mac.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks for the example./ I used that to start from scratch and it works. It must have been some incorrect setting. I still had InputTransparent somewhere set to True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with 'InputTransparent="True"', after rebuilding the page step by step based on comments from ToolmakerSteve I was able to fix it. Thanks for all the help.

**Code**

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="NumberCommand" CommandParameter="1"/>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"  Text="1"  FontSize="Title" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"></Label>
                <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text=" " FontSize="Small" TextColor="Black"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

**Code behind**

```
private async void NumberCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button1 = (TapGestureRecognizer)sender;
    string commandParameter = button1.CommandParameter.ToString();
}
```